# How to avoid the Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <button> in <div>

Tags: next.js, zoom-sdk

I was trying to integrate Zoom into my website. I am using NextJS.
There was one error earlier telling - window is undefined. I understand that the server cannot have the window object and so this error. I have fixed the error but not sure if that's the correct way of doing. I feel its a hack :). Will really appreciate if someone can suggest me in getting that right.
Even with the fix given, I see one more warning which I want to avoid.
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .
Again, this is because of the code generated by server did not have Button but when in client, it renders the button. This was done as a part of the fix. Is there any good way to overcome this issue?
[Sample code link](https://github.com/SamplesForMurthy/sampleCode) for your reference.

Also there two errors when I run the app,

```
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/css/bootstrap.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
TestPage:1 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/css/react-select.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

But both the files are present in the folder!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should move your import outside the component

```js
const Zoom = dynamic(() => import("../components/Zoom/Zoom"), { ssr: false });
```

Also make sure to use **Link** from `next/link` not from `@material-ui/core`

`pages/TestPage.js`

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const Zoom = dynamic(() => import("../components/Zoom/Zoom"), { ssr: false });

function TestPage(props) {
  const [zoomMeeting, setZoomMeeting] = useState(false);
  const [loadClientContents, setLoadClientContents] = useState(false);
  const startZoomMeeting = () => {
    setZoomMeeting(!zoomMeeting);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoadClientContents(!loadClientContents);
  }, []);

  const getContent = () => {
    {
      return zoomMeeting ? (
        <Zoom />
      ) : (
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          onClick={startZoomMeeting}
          style={{ marginLeft: "30px" }}
        >
          Zoom call
        </Button>
      );
    }
  };

  return <div>{getContent()}</div>;
}

export default TestPage;
```